Behaviour diff b/w SELECT and UPDATE for range_optimizer_max_mem_size in MySQL
I have a table called example_table with 7 million rows, and the range_optimizer_max_mem_size is set to 2MB. I understand that if a query's range memory exceeds this limit, the optimizer switches to a full table scan. However, I noticed something interesting: when I run an UPDATE query with 4,000 IDs, it exceeds the limit and defaults to a full table scan. But when I convert that UPDATE into a SELECT query using the same 4,000 IDs, it does not exceed the range_optimizer_max_mem_size.
Can someone help me understand the difference in behavior between the SELECT and UPDATE queries?
Attached the table and test details below,
MySQL Version : 5.7.18
mysql> show create table example_table;
+---------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table         | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
+---------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| example_table | CREATE TABLE `example_table` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `age` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `name` (`name`),
  KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7000001 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+---------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show indexes from example_table;
+---------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table         | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+---------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| example_table |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | id          | A         |           4 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| example_table |          1 | name     |            1 | name        | A         |           4 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| example_table |          1 | email    |            1 | email       | A         |           4 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+---------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> select count(*) from example_table;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  7000000 |
+----------+
1 row in set (1.22 sec)


mysql> explain UPDATE example_table SET age=100 where (id IN (<4k ids>) and ((id >= 1) and (id <= 7000000)));
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table         | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows    | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | UPDATE      | example_table | NULL       | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 8       | NULL | 7000000 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.10 sec)



mysql> explain Select * from example_table where (id IN (<4k ids>) and ((id >= 1) and (id <= 7000000)));
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table         | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | example_table | NULL       | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       | NULL | 4000 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+



select count(*) from example_table; in 1.22 sec seems to be very slow. Usually, count(*) for a complete table is optimized by reading the metrics.

@Wiimm That only works for MyISAM tables. It doesn't work for any storage engine that supports MVCC, such as InnoDB.

Can this be reproduced in 8.x? If not, there's probably little point in trying to explain the behavior of an obsolete version.

Hi @Barmar, thanks for the reply,
I have tried in 8.0.37, But there for both SELECT and UPDATE query, range_optimizer_max_mem_size has been exceeded and full_table scan done.

So it seems like something that has been fixed, and the question is moot now.
